# Getting error: Non-static method Phactory\Sql\Phactory::reset() should not be called statically

Tags: symfony, phpunit, phactory

I have a trivially small PHPUnit test that looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Tests\Entity;
namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity;

use VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Phactory\Sql\Phactory;

class UserTest extends EntityTest
{
    public function testCreate()
    {   
        Phactory::reset();
    }   
}
```

When I try to run it, I get this:

```
There was 1 error:

1) VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\UserTest::testCreate
ErrorException: Runtime Notice: Non-static method Phactory\Sql\Phactory::reset() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /Users/jason/Web/pressbox/src/VNN/PressboxBundle/Tests/Entity/UserTest.php line 13
```

What's up with that? All the docs call it statically.

I'm doing this on Symfony 2.0, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says you should be using the top-level `Phactory` class directly under `lib/`--not the individual implementations such as `Phactory/Sql/Phactory` which get instantiated based on the `PDO` object you pass to `setConnection`. Change

```
use Phactory\Sql\Phactory;
```

to

```
require_once 'Phactory/lib/Phactory.php';
```

The main class is in the global namespace and doesn't require a `use` statement.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have a `Phactory.php` in `Phactory/lib`. I installed Phactory using Composer, and the entry looks like this: `"chriskite/phactory": "*"`

Comment: And on GitHub, there's no `Phactory.php` in `lib`. https://github.com/chriskite/phactory/tree/next/lib

Comment: Another clue: the download page at phactory.org links to `Phactory-0.1.0.tgz`, but the most recent version of Phactory is apparently 0.3.2. Perhaps everything on the site is outdated.

Comment: @JasonSwett - The PEAR installer created that file. I didn't try using Composer. You should probably create an issue on Github to get the author's attention. :)

Comment: Hmm, the PEAR installer didn't create any file at all for me. Plus it claimed to do something with version 0.2.0, which would by now be outdated.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to try to use Phactory anymore. I'm just going to accept this answer anyway since I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chriskite/phactory/issues/30

> From the code, setConnection, define and create are not static functions but the README and website guide do not reflect that.

e.g.  test code
https://github.com/chriskite/phactory/blob/next/tests/Phactory/Sql/PhactoryTest.php

```
use Phactory\Sql\Phactory;
...
$this->pdo = new \PDO("sqlite:test.db");
$this->phactory = new Phactory($this->pdo);
$this->phactory->define('user');
$this->phactory->reset();
```

I don't know when it has been changed.

Too late anyways...

Answer (score 0):

The current version, 0.3.2, is not backward compatible with the static method structure that is documented.

Here is the breaking commit: https://github.com/chriskite/phactory/commit/d3b60eeedea955ab7b5803ec29446d19888d3849

Unfortunately, the documentation has not been updated on http://phactory.org and the pearhub repo is no longer available.

I would look to the tests for examples: https://github.com/chriskite/phactory/blob/next/tests/Phactory/Sql/PhactoryTest.php